# Wordpress Problem: Redirects login/logout Problem session_tokens disappear after logout

Tags: wordpress, authentication, session, redirect, token

I have Redirects Issue in WordPress. After updating to the new Version Wordpress 5.2.2. Every time I try to login, the Site is redirecting me again to the login page. I find out that the session_tokens in the database/table wp_usermeta is deleting everytime after logout.

What I already tried and how I found the Bug

1. Clearing Browser Cookies and Cache
2. Restore Default .htaccess file
3. Deactivating Themes and Plugins
4. Deleted Themes and Plugins and reinstalled everything

All this steps above did not help, then I observed my wp_usermeta table and found, that the session_tokens was missing!

Session_tokens: I found out that the session_tokens to the database wp_usermeta was everytime disappearing after logout. If I do insert it manuel thru sql again in the database, then it works for one time and I can login again. After logout it disappears again. So I need everytime to put it again in the DB if I want to login to my wordpress admin site.

sql: INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('965', '1', 'session_tokens', NULL);

I know now what the Problem is, but I have no Idea how to fix it? It has to do something with logout?

Sorry: for my grammatical, not perfect English!

Redirect URL: https://www.example.de/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.de%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: Hey! I have a similar kind of issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

here is code for redirect logout user to the homepage. add this to **function.php**

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_after_logout');

function auto_redirect_after_logout(){

  wp_redirect( home_url() );
  exit();

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but it did not worked. After logout the session_tokens still deleting. :-(

Comment: okay Try this one. this is working on my website.

**//redirect to homepage

function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
    // check if user is leaving from admin
    // is_admin() check would not work here probably as we left the admin already
    if ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'wp-admin' ) ){
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yourdomain.com' );
    } else {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yourdomain.com' );
    }
    //make sure to call exit after redirect
    exit;
}
**